# What is the equivalent of dispatch_block_t in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have some objective-c code that I would like to understand in order to do the same in swift:

```
dispatch_block_t adjustTooltipVisibility = ^{
    self.tooltipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    self.tooltipTipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0;
};
```

So far all I could find out about `dispatch_block_t` was that it's used in dispatch_after in swift as a closure. So I can understand that but I don't understand the use of it just like this in objective-c and how to transform this code into swift code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dispatch_block_t` is a type alias for a `Void -> Void` closure. Swift (as of version 1.2) doesn't infer those very well, so you'll need to declare the type. You'll also need to reference `self` explicitly to access instance properties, and will want to make sure you're not creating a reference cycle. Declaring `self` as `weak` in the closure is one safe approach:

```
let adjustTooltipVisibility: dispatch_block_t = { [weak self] in
    if self?._tooltipVisible == true {
        self?.tooltipView.alpha = 1
        self?.tooltipTipView.alpha = 1
    } else {
        self?.tooltipView.alpha = 0
        self?.tooltipTipView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the use of it in that case?

Comment: Your use of weak self is very bad. A weak reference can disappear at any time, including during a message being sent. Much better to do an initial if (let strongself = self).

Comment: Why this `dispatch_block_t` is used for? What's the difference if I don't use it?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5,

`dispatch_block_t` is an alias for `()->Void`

---

```
let adjustTooltipVisibility: ()->Void = {
    self.tooltipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0
    self.tooltipTipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let adjustTooltipVisibility:Void->Void = {
    self.tooltipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0
    self.tooltipTipView.alpha = _tooltipVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0
};
```

If there will be something leading to retain cycle, you should use the unowned capture to self.
The type of the block is Void->Void

Comment: The ^ is a copy-paste error, and the self and the type inference should be added indeed. I will update the result.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 version objective-c and swift5 to you can compare

Objective-C version

```objectivec
dispatch_block_t completionBlock = ^{
// run your code in completion block
}

// start task in background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    // update completion block in main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),completionBlock);
};
```

Swift 5 version

```swift
let completionBlock: () -> Void = {[weak self] in
// run your code in completion block
// using `[weak self] in` to avoid memory leak 
}
// start task in background thread        
DispatchQueue.global().async {[weak self] in
   // update completion block in main thread
   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: completionBlock)
}
```